# In Asp.net MVC 5, how do I implement Identity storage provider in a custom user entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have an Asp.net MVC 5 application which is using the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` provider classes. How do I implement my own version of the Users and roles tables and still using Identity provides for AspNet?

I have my own Class User(username,password) and i want to use the Identity for log in.

UPDATE

I've solved my problem, using a table whit relation one to one from AspNetUSer to my new table User.

Comment: I dont know about asp.net mvc5, and what is a common practice for it. But in older versions you can just make your own implementation of IPrincipal and IIdentity.

Comment: I'm not sure that editing of the question this way will help to answer the question for OP. The original question was not about storage providers at all.

Comment: The OP needed to use their own, existing DB tables with Identity, so don't they need to write their own providers?

Comment: I've solved my problem, using a table whit relation one to one from AspNetUSer to my new table User.